# paypal subscription working scheme

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

I was reading lots of paypal guides and tutorials. And I want to clearify how it works:

1 STEP. I create simple form to send data to paypal.

Example:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="mail@mail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Subscribe">
</form>
```

2 STEP. I create IPN script and get notification about payment status.

Question: Maybe is there secure solution for 1 step? because i need to show IPN link, user id and etc...

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make it more secure is to use the paid APIs (Payments Pro + Recurring Payments API, with each having its own fee). Otherwise, IPN will send you notices securely (provided you validate the IPN calls).

Comment: Which APIs are paid and which are not ? https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/recurring_payment_ec/php?interactive=OFF&env=sandbox

Comment: Payments Pro is $30/mo
Recurring Payments API is also $30/mo AND requires Payments Pro

Comment: so there are no Recurring Payments for free ? I thought i need only business account..

Comment: No, there are free recurring payments (minus PayPal fees), but you wanted secure. The only way to make it secure is to use an API and the API isn't free, but gives you far more control.

Comment: ok thank you. and if without api? will be fee per transaction ?

Comment: All transactions, regardless of API or not, will incur a PayPal fee.

Comment: So if I want to use recurring payments I need to pay 30$/month + each transaction %.

Comment: [Payments Basic Subscriptions](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_subscr-intro-outside) do NOT have a $30/mo fee, but that was what you referenced in your question

Comment: Ok thank you so I will try with basic payments without api. In this basic will be IPN to check if all ok ?